# Facebook OAuthException - This authorization code has expired. [code=100]

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, coldfusion, cfml

I have setup the Facebook API SDK for ColdFusion - https://github.com/affinitiz/facebook-cf-sdk

I've setup a login process which works successfully but after 10 minutes or so when I return and refresh the page, it shows the following error:

This authorization code has expired. [code=100]

Is there something I am missing with the FB login? Am I meant to be checking against something manually in order to persist the session?

Cheers

Shaun

```
<cfscript>
   import facebook.sdk.FacebookApp;
   import facebook.sdk.FacebookGraphAPI;

   // Replace this with your appId and secret
   APP_ID = "";
   SECRET_KEY = "";
   SCOPE = "publish_stream";

   if (APP_ID is "" or SECRET_KEY is "") {
       // App not configured
       facebookGraphAPI = new FacebookGraphAPI();
   } else {
       // Create facebookApp instance
       facebookApp = new FacebookApp(appId=APP_ID, secretKey=SECRET_KEY);

       // See if there is a user from a cookie or session
       userId = facebookApp.getUserId();
       if (userId) {
           try {
               userAccessToken = facebookApp.getUserAccessToken();
               facebookGraphAPI = new FacebookGraphAPI(accessToken=userAccessToken, appId=APP_ID);
               userObject = facebookGraphAPI.getObject(id=userId);
               userFriends = facebookGraphAPI.getConnections(id=userId, type='friends', limit=10);
               authenticated = true;
           } catch (any exception) {
               // Usually an invalid session (OAuthInvalidTokenException), for example if the user logged out from facebook.com
              // this is where the error occurs
              userId = 0;
              facebookGraphAPI = new FacebookGraphAPI();
           }
       } else {
           facebookGraphAPI = new FacebookGraphAPI();
       }

       // Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
       if (userId) {
           logoutUrl = facebookApp.getLogoutUrl();
       } else {
           parameters = {scope=SCOPE};
           loginUrl = facebookApp.getLoginUrl(parameters);
       }
   }
```

Comment: Is there an `expires_in` member in one of the OAuth responses?

Comment: Not that I've noticed. What is weird though is if you refresh the page again, the login seems active again. Any ideas?

Comment: The `code` is supposed to be used once, immediately after you receive it, in order to obtain an access token - you use the access token to call the API - are you trying to use the same code more than once?

Comment: Igy - I've added the code that I'm using. The access_token is stored in a session variable from what I can see in the SDK so that is being used.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you're not exchanging the OAuth code to an Access Token. See the docs here how to do that: [Manually Build a Login Flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#confirm)