# Facebook Graph Error This authorization code has expired

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Hi Sir Am Using Fb Php Sdk 4 & Graph 2.8 I Know Its Little Outdated But I Want Continue On It. Only Authorized Problem Fixed Can Make My Project Done

I Used Configured & Login Data Page Below But Its Return Me

Graph returned an error: This authorization code has been used.

below my code

config.php

```
  <?php
session_start();
$_IM=array(
    "sitename" => "AppsFunny",
    "siteurl" => "http://appsfunny.com",
    "sitelogo" => "AppsFunny.Com",
    "fb_page" => "/appsfunny",
    "aurl" => "appsfunny.com"
    );
include "ifunc.php";
include "db.php";
include "Unicode2Bijoy.class.php";
$app_id='423436984657946';
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => $app_id,
  'app_secret' => 'c82ff16cec2f6a055302c5c632c0129b',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8',
]);




if (isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
  $token = $session->getToken();
   try {
              // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
              $response = $fb->get('/me', $token);
            } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
              echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
              exit;
            } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
              echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
              exit;
            }

            $user = $response->getGraphUser();

                  $_SESSION['FBID'] = $user['id'];           
                  $_SESSION['FULLNAME'] = $user['name'];
                  $_SESSION['propic']="https://graph.facebook.com/".$_SESSION['FBID']."/picture?height=200&width=200";
            }


?>
```

and login.php

```
      <?php 
        require_once __DIR__ . '/config.php'; 
$p=$_GET["p"]; 
        $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

        $_SESSION['FBRLH_state']=$_GET['state']; 

        try { 
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken(); 
        }
         catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) { 
        // When Graph returns an error 
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage(); exit; 
        } 

        catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) { 
        // When validation fails or other local issues 
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage(); 
        exit; 
        } 

        if (isset($accessToken)) { 
        $access_token = $session->getToken(); 
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = (string) $accessToken; 
    header("location:".$p); 
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook OAuthException - This authorization code has expired. \[code=100\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21741186/facebook-oauthexception-this-authorization-code-has-expired-code-100)

Comment: I try that sir but not work

Comment: Please format the login.php code in a readable way. And btw., if you are not just trying to fix an old, existing system here, but are creating something new - then I would strongly recommend that you use the PHP SDK v5, instead of the outdated v4.

Comment: login.php readable bro. I waste much time on that so want complete the project in same version

Answer (score 0):

### Cause

This problem is there because you are trying to request `access_token` on every page load or reload. When you request a token, a unique code is get passed along with the URL. When you request again and again with the same token, this error occurs.

### Solution

So after getting `access_token`, keep it in `db`. And request for new token only and only if either you don't have `access_token` or its not valid anymore.